# How to upload powerpoint file to server phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, file-upload

Hello I Want to upload a powerpoint file using phonegap file transfer protocol to my local java server thru ios simulator, the location of the file on the phone is passed to the handleOpenURL function when the user selects to open a powerpoint with my app. The problem is that nothing is happening although im sure this method is executing??!! can anyone help please?

```
function handleOpenURL(url)
        {

            setTimeout(function() {
                      alert(url);

                jQuery.get( "http://192.168.1.100:8080/PpServer/getnumberofslides" ,  function( data ) {
                    numberofslides=data;
                    alert( "Load was performed." + data );
                });
                       fileURL = url;
                       function win(r) {
                       console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
                       console.log("Response = " + r.response);
                       console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);

                     //  processapplication();
                       }

                       function fail(error) {
                       alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
                       console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                       console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
                       }

                       var uri = encodeURI("http://192.168.1.100:8080/NewServerlet");

                       var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                       options.fileKey="file";
                       options.fileName=fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                       options.mimeType="multipart/form-data";
                       options.httpMethod="Post"
                     // options.params = {"file"};
                       var headers={'headerParam':'file'};

                     //  options.headers = headers;

                     var ft = new FileTransfer();
                       ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
                       if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                       loadingStatus.setPercentage(progressEvent.loaded /                                  progressEvent.total);
                       } else {
                       loadingStatus.increment();
                       }
                       };
                       ft.upload(fileURL, uri, win, fail, options);
                       }, 0);
          //  
        }
```

Comment: Have you added your server to white list in phonegap?

Comment: Thank you for the response yes I did but nothing has change I can make an ajax get requests successfully but I cant upload a file with this code